# Hyphen character encoded as “%2D” with IIS6

Tags: iis-6, 301-redirect, firefox, encoding, seo

A customer has set up a website on a server IIS6. In older versions of Firefox, they have a problem with a URL containing a hyphen character.  When they request

```
http://www.example.es/mas-info
```

they get a 301 redirect to

```
http://www.example.es/mas%2Dinfo
```

The hyphen is replaced by the "%2D" code, and they want to continue seeing the hyphen.

The obvious answer that we have given to the customer, is that the problem is solved by upgrading to II7 or using a newer version of Firefox, but it seems that these options are not possible for them.

Exist any other way to solve the problem?

They are tested using Firefox 20.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30480490/1591669)